# swap method for a class inherited from enable_shared_from_this<...>

Tags: c++, c++20, copy-and-swap, enable-shared-from-this

I have implemented a swap method for my class that inherits from `enable_shared_from_this<...>`

```
class X : public enable_shared_from_this<X> {
    int x;
    friend void swap(X& x1, X& x2) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(x1.x, x2.x);
    }
    X& operator=(X other) {
       swap(*this, other);
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried to swap the `enable_shared_from_this<...>` part in the `swap` method by adding either:

```
std::enable_shared_from_this<X>::swap(first, second);
```

Doesn't compile because of:

> No member named 'swap' in 'std::enable_shared_from_this'

```
swap(static_cast<std::enable_shared_from_this<X>>(first), static_cast<std::enable_shared_from_this<X>>(second));
```

Doesn't compile because of:

> Calling a protected constructor of class 'std::enable_shared_from_this' protected constructor can only be used to construct a base class subobject

Finally I resorted to adding the following line in the assignment operator:

```
std::enable_shared_from_this<X>::operator=(other);
```

But this feels wrong to me because the `swap` method is incomplete and in general mixing two idioms (I guess).

So what is the correct way to handle this...?

Note: I'm using C++20.

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Was the `swap` here supposed to be a `friend`?

Comment: @Barry Yes, sorry, I forgot to add it. Did it now.

Answer (score 2):

`enable_shared_from_this` technically has a copy constructor and assignment operator. But they don't meaningfully *work*. Neither of them copies the `weak_this` internal member. So even after assignment, the `weak_this` will be the same.

Swapping is not functionality that `enable_shared_from_this` supports.

Note that swapping them wouldn't actually make sense. The `shared_ptr`s managing the memory for each object point to the specific objects they manage. Swapping objects only swaps their *contents*; the address of the two objects remains the same. So the managed storage should still refer to the original objects because their addresses didn't change.

As such, it makes sense that you cannot "copy" or "swap" `enable_shared_from_this`. So just leave the base class subobjects alone.

Comment: This makes sense to me if my shared pointers share the same resource for all objects of this class, but in my case the shared pointers do not (necessarily) do that... (in the case the object is copied/moved/assigned they should be the same, but not necessarily when I want to swap them... in fact, my case is a bit more complicated with multiple virtual inheritance but I *think* that part is not related... if it is I'll post another question with more details...)

Comment: What you said doesn't make sense. You have two objects, A and B. Each of them has a separate shared state. That shared state contains the *addresses* of A and B. If you swap the contents of A and B... their addresses *do not change*. Even if logically A now has the contents and behavior of the old B, it is still *object A* and *not* object B. It does not *become* B; it merely contains B's old data. The shared states still point to A and not B.

Comment: @traveh: You cannot change the pointers being managed by the shared states themselves. They aren't even part of `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @traveh: "*my case is a bit more complicated with multiple virtual inheritance*" Irrelevant. You cannot logically swap objects of different types. I mean, you can make it technically work, but you've stepped far out of the domain of what "swap" is supposed to actually mean.

Comment: Oh I think I understand... but what if one of them is actually empty (i.e. nullptr)...? In this case I'm supposed to fill it with an empty state and swap the empty state's contents with the other one?